# htaccess url with usernames

Tags: .htaccess

What i wanted  to do is first hide all .php extensions in my URL secondly i wanted all users to have there pages with there usernames like `www.domain.com/username`
however i can easily do the first with this code in my `.htaccess`.

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)$ $1.php
```

Now how can i do the second part as if somebody goes to this domain `www.domain.com/username` server will route to `www.domain.com/username.php` but it should go to URL like `www.domain.com/profile.php?id=username`.

How can i achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this, however it will redirect everything after the / to profile.php, so you have to make rules for all other urls before this, if needed.

```
RewriteRule (.*) profile.php?id=$1
```

Comment: you mean to say php rules ? or rules in htaccess... but what if i write this www.domain.com/artist-signup   it will go to  profile.php ?  it should go to www.domain.com/artist-signup.php can u please guide or make rules if its in .htacess

Comment: What you can do is RewriteRule (.*) $1.php

This is a rule for .htaccess.

Comment: actually your not telling it the things i need to know 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
i think i should change them for !-f before using the  above Rewrite Rule u mentioned 
RewriteRule (.*) profile.php?id=$1